# Image Source Property - Inside DataTemplate and UserControl.Resources - Image from different assembly

Tags: wpf, xaml

Using the Image Source Property just works, if I'm not inside a DataTemplate.
Otherwise he cannot find the picture which is in another assembly named "Images".

XAML, that works. I can see the Image, holded by the "Images" assembly:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Views.ViewUserInfo"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d"              
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="600">

    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,5,0,5">
            <TextBlock Text="Authorized: "/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=IsAuthorized, Mode=OneWay}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            <Image Width="16" Height="16" Source="/Images;Component/Img16/Ok.png" />
         </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

Does not work:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Views.ViewUserInfo"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d"              
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="600">

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type System:Boolean}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="DataTemplate has been found " />
                <Image Width="16" Height="16" Source="/Images;Component/Img16/Ok.png" />
            </StackPanel>
            <DataTemplate.Resources>
                <!--simplyfied, Triggers removed...--->
            </DataTemplate.Resources>
        </DataTemplate>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,5,0,5">
            <TextBlock Text="Authorized: "/>
            <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Path=IsAuthorized, Mode=OneWay}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            <!--IsAuthorized.GetType() = typeof(System.Boolean)-->
         </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

He's actually in the DataTemplate, because he shows me the Text "DataTemplate has been found" but i cannot see any picture..
Whats the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

You said you see the text box, how can that be, your template is empty, your StackPanel is just a resource in your DataTemplate. Try removing the `<DataTemplate.Resources>` and `</DataTemplate.Resources>` lines or maybe add your  `<!--simplyfied, Triggers removed...--->`.

Comment: sorry, i did really bad copy&paste ;) xaml is corrected. The content of <DataTemplate.Resources> does not matter, even if I remove the whole <DataTemplate.Resources> part, i just see the TextBlock.

Answer (score 0):

Dont use ContentPresenter. Use ContentControl.

```
   <ContentControl Content="{Binding Path=IsAuthorized, Mode=OneWay}" 
                     VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
```